# IntelliJ: Paste content of a file to hastebin.com

Tags: intellij-idea, xubuntu

I'm searching for a simple way to paste the content of a file directly from IntelliJ into [hastebin](http://hastebin.com).

But I didn't find any plugin for IntelliJ. 
I'm running IntelliJ on Xubuntu 14.12.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi we used the following solution provided here: https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-client

By using a simple Bash Script and External Tools in Intellij.

**Bash Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
hastepost() { a=$(cat); curl -X POST -s -d "$a" hastebin.com/documents | awk -F '"' '{print "hastebin.com/"$4}'; }

url=$(cat $1 | hastepost)
echo $url
xdg-open $url
```

If you do not need to open the browser when execution is finished just remove the last line of the bash script.

Then create a new **External Tool** in Intellij with the following parameters:

[image]

Where `/home/user/Dev/TOOLS/hastebin/hastebin.sh` is the path to your bash script.